# Storing lines in variable in dynamic text

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to store each line from a text file to do some processing. 
The text file is dynamic, it will grow with more search entries.
The problem is that if the original text file have 10 entry, it will only loop 10 times even if it have not finish the loop, more entries are added. Is it possible to loop the other new entries in the same loop?

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set /p search_parameter="Type your search: "

rem run grep seach commmand
grep -nri %search_parameter% --colour --include=*.{c,h} > text.txt

rem filter required lines into new text file
type text.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text2.txt

set /A count=0
rem read text file line-by-line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
   set /A count+=1
   set "line=%%G"
   for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%~nxi"

   if NOT "!line!"=="!line:.h=!" (
      grep -nri !line! --colour --include=*.{c,h} >> text2.txt
      rem echo %%G
   )
   echo count: !count!
   echo line: !line!
)
rem type text2.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text3.txt

pause

echo on
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process each input line until the EndOfFile of a dynamic growing file
set "count=0"
call :ProcessFile < test.txt >> test.txt
echo %count% lines processed...
goto :EOF


:ProcessFile

rem Read next line
set "line="
set /P "line="

rem Test if EOF found
if not defined line goto :EOF

set /A count+=1
echo %count%- %line% > CON

rem Randomly generate a new line
if %time:~-1% geq 5 echo Added %line%

goto ProcessFile
```

Output example:

```
1- Line one
2- Line two
3- Line three
4- Added Line one
5- Added Line two
6- Added Line three
7- Added Added Line one
8- Added Added Line two
9- Added Added Line three
10- Added Added Added Line one
10 lines processed...
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would repeatedly read the file, skipping the lines already processed, until the end is reached.  I will give a short example code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=1

:loopfor
for /F "%skip% tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
   echo %%G
   set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
   set /a cnt+=1
   goto :loopfor
)

echo We make it here when there are no lines in the file that we haven't already processed.
```

The variable `skip` is needed because `for /f "skip=0" ...` produces an error.
To explain:
Basically the actual `for` loop reads the "next" line, increments a counter, and breaks the for loop by `GO`ing `TO` the loopfor label and repeating.  We keep track of the "next" line using the incremented `cnt` variable and then skipping that number of lines.  The (huge) downside is reading that file over and over and over and over again.
I would actually probably use a subroutine like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=1

:loopfor
for /F "%skip% tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
   call :process "%%~G"
   goto :loopfor
)

echo We make it here when there are no lines in the file that we haven't already processed.

goto :eof

:process
echo %~1
set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
set /a cnt+=1
goto :eof
```

I'll try to shoehorn this concept into your code, but you'll have to test it thoroughly.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set /p search_parameter="Type your search: "

rem run grep seach commmand
grep -nri %search_parameter% --colour --include=*.{c,h} > text.txt

rem filter required lines into new text file
type text.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text2.txt

rem you might be able to use the variable count, but I'll add cnt anyway
set /A count=0
rem read text file line-by-line

rem Adding to your original code starting here

set cnt=0
set skip=
:loopfor
for /F "%skip% tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
   set /A count+=1
   set "line=%%G"
   for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%~nxi"

   if NOT "!line!"=="!line:.h=!" (
      grep -nri !line! --colour --include=*.{c,h} >> text2.txt
      rem echo %%G
   )
   echo count: !count!
   echo line: !line!
   set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
   set /a cnt+=1
   goto :loopfor
)
rem type text2.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text3.txt

pause

echo on
```

Note -- this does not in any way account for the file shrinking.  It can only grow.
If you want to get a little more fancy, you could wait for more input:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=1

:loopfor
for /F "%skip% tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
   echo %%G
   set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
   set /a cnt+=1
   goto :loopfor
)

rem We reached the end of the file.  Pause 10 seconds and then scan the file again.
timeout /t 10 >nul
goto :loopfor
```

This will wait forever.  But it's not exactly an infinite loop because eventually either the `for` loop will choke on how big the `skip=` number becomes, **OR** you'll reach the cmd limit of around 2 billion (I think) for the `set /a cnt+=1` command -- presuming the input file continues to grow.

Comment: i am receiving this error
 tokens=* delims=" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: That would happen if the variable `cnt` isn't initialized prior to the `for` loop.